# Cannot push files to remote

Tags: git, bitbucket

I spent some time here but I still couldn't find the answer to my problem.
I try to push files remote but it still gives me this message:

```
git push origin master
```

Execution...

```
Counting objects: 101, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (95/95), done.
```

> fatal: unable to read c14d62cb647e6ecf590df812d91e2e4bf02f1eb4
>       error: remote unpack failed: eof before pack header was fully read
>       error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:xxxx'

To be honest I don't know what to do. I tried to pull files first, then I tried to push it again. I also tried to make new remote repo but it didn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: quick google search says this can be a result of pushing submodules to a non-submodule aware remote (which would be surprising on bitbucket) or disk space issues on the local

Answer (score 0):

I found answer in git-repair command - it helped with this.

Comment: Sorry. 
https://git-repair.branchable.com to this. In my case it helped with every errors.